# Get multiple checkbox value with Ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, checkbox

I have trouble cant get multiple value from check box with Ajax. I can get one checkbox value but multiple value not work.
Here is my HTML code

```
  <input name="p_flatform" class="p_flatform" type="checkbox" value="1">Iphone
 <input name="p_flatform" class="p_flatform" type="checkbox" value="2">Ipad
<input name="p_flatform" class="p_flatform" type="checkbox" value="3">Android
```

And this is my Ajax

```
$.ajax({
        url: 'quotation_validation',
       type: 'post',
       data: { p_flatform:$('input[name="p_flatform"]:checked').val()},
```

It didnt work. Please help.

Comment: what do you want? An array of the checked values?

Answer (score 0):

```js
var arr = [];
$.each($('input[name="p_flatform"]:checked'), function() {
  var value = $(this).val()

  arr.push(value)

})
console.log(arr)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input name="p_flatform" class="p_flatform" type="checkbox" value="1" checked>Iphone
<input name="p_flatform" class="p_flatform" type="checkbox" value="2">Ipad
<input name="p_flatform" class="p_flatform" type="checkbox" value="3" checked>Android
```

Iterate on each checkbox to get all the value.
Push each value on array.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use `.map()`, like so:

```
$('input[name="p_flatform"]:checked').map(function () { return $(this).val(); }).get();
```

Giving you:

```
data: { p_flatform:$('input[name="p_flatform"]:checked').map(function () { return $(this).val(); }).get()},
```